# i have added a change to my while loop and i want it to add the change but show what i have added

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('Welcome to Loot Box Simulator!')

gems = 0
boxes = 0
boxes_opened = 0
gem_cost = 19.95
gem_amount = 550
box_cost = 100
items = list

choice = ('')
while True :
    print ('You have',gem_amount, 'gems and', boxes, 'Loot boxes.')
    print ('Choose from the following options:')
    print ('1) Buy gems', gem_amount, 'gems for just', gem_cost)
    print ('2) Buy loot box (costs', box_cost, 'gems)')
    print ('3) Open loot box')
    print('4) View statistics')
    print('5) Quit')
    break
a = gem_amount + gems
if input == 'a':
    gems = gems+550
    print ('a',gem_amount)
    print ('Thank you for you purchase!')
```

after the 550 is added i would like the questions to re appear with 550 added to the gem amount? i would like it to reappear with you have 550 gems and 0 loot boxes and the game will request the person to choose again.

Comment: The does not compile, and noes not ask the user for a choice, you may call `input()`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right:

```
print('Welcome to Loot Box Simulator!')

gems = 0
boxes = 0
boxes_opened = 0
gem_cost = 19.95
gem_amount = 550
box_cost = 100
items = list

choice = ('')
while True :
    print ('You have', gems, 'gems and', boxes, 'Loot boxes.')
    print ('Choose from the following options:')
    print ('1) Buy gems', gem_amount, 'gems for just', gem_cost)
    print ('2) Buy loot box (costs', box_cost, 'gems)')
    print ('3) Open loot box')
    print('4) View statistics')
    print('5) Quit')
    a = gem_amount + gems
    if input() == 'a':
        gems += 550
        print (a, gem_amount)
        print ('Thank you for you purchase!')
```

You displays before amount of gems in shop, just change to 'gems' in first print, and put if with input to loop, program will wait for input every time